# Jerarquia de las sugerencias de vs code

Tags: vscode

Estoy desarrollando una extensión para VS Code [VueBindThis](https://github.com/DeniferSantiago/VueBindThis) la cual es un tipo de Intellisense donde agrego sugerencias a partir del api de VS Code.

El problema es que las sugerencias que agrega la extensión aparecen abajo del todo y quisiera que aparezca entre las primeras posibilidades.

Muestras:

[image]

Ejemplo de como agrego las sugerencias:

```
function activate(context) {
    let provider1 = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('javascript', {
        provideCompletionItems(document, position, token, context) {
            const thisCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('this');
            thisCompletion.commitCharacters = ['.'];
            thisCompletion.documentation = new vscode.MarkdownString('Press `.` to get `this.`');
            return [
                thisCompletion
            ];
        }
    });
    context.subscriptions.push(provider1);
}
```

Comment: El orden de las sugerencias es definido por cada usuario, el API de VSCode no te permitirá modificar a tu gusto las sugerencias del usuario, esto por buenas prácticas de usabilidad.

Comment: Eso estaba leyendo, pero veo que desactivar la sugerencias basadas en palabras ayuda mucho